# Что означает ' ? ' в данном выражении?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

```
interface PaletteColor {
  light?: string;
  main: string;
  dark?: string;
  contrastText?: string;
}
```

Comment: «interface property question mark» — гугл говорит, это опциональное свойство.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

значит, что это свойство можно и не указывать иначе обязательно надо задавать все 4 параметра, а так можно обойтись только одним `main`

Answer (score 2):

Необязательное свойство. Вопросительный знак, ставится в случае, если свойство может без указания параметра.